# How to right Align UILabel on cell tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alignment, uilabel

I to create one project that has tableview class in self.
I have 3 thing in any cell of tableview. (1 button (left side) and 2 lable like bottom image)

[image]

I want title cell to be right alignment but I couldn't do it.

this is my code. where is my mistake :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        _backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"copymove-cell-bg"]];
        [_backgroundImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopRight];
        [self setBackgroundView:_backgroundImageView];
        [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        _iconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_iconButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 47, 50)];
        [_iconButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
        [_iconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iconButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item-icon-folder"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item-icon-folder-selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item-icon-folder-selected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_iconButton];

        _titleTextField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69, 29, _titleTextField.frame.size.width, _titleTextField.frame.size.height)];
        [_titleTextField setFont:KOFONT_FILES_TITLE];
        [_titleTextField setTextColor:KOCOLOR_FILES_TITLE];
        [_titleTextField.layer setShadowColor:KOCOLOR_FILES_TITLE_SHADOW.CGColor];
        [_titleTextField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
        [_titleTextField.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        [_titleTextField.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
        [_titleTextField.layer setShadowRadius:0.0f];
        [_titleTextField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [_titleTextField setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_titleTextField];
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        _countLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(273, 29, 47, 28)];
        [_countLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
        [_countLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item-counter"]]];
        [_countLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [_countLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];
        [_countLabel setFont:KOFONT_FILES_COUNTER];
        [_countLabel setTextColor:KOCOLOR_FILES_COUNTER];
        [_countLabel setShadowColor:KOCOLOR_FILES_COUNTER_SHADOW];
        [_countLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];

        [self setAccessoryView:_countLabel];
        [self.accessoryView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: u may try having a nib for the TableView Cell so that u do not have to give the frames in the code and the code will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: try to using same label width?

Comment: @tom19830924 I do it but not working :(

Comment: @Ishank my friend please tell me more!!!

Comment: my friends how to create custom cell with xib file and put in UITable View?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS6,

use `[_countLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];` because UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated in iOS6.

To align right,

```
[_countLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine at my end. Please check width and height you are passing to the labels. Just check your code by setting widths and height of your labels.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
_titleTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment =  
         UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight
```

Answer (score 0):

First `UITextAlignmentRight` is `deprecated` `in iOS6`, so you should use:

```
_titleTextField.textAlignment = 2;
```

Second, you need to check your `UILabel Frame`. Check for `CGFloat x, CGFloat y` and the `width` of your `UILable`.

> textAlignment = 0 (LeftAlignment).
>   textAlignment = 1 (CenterAlignment).
>   textAlignment = 2 (RightAlignment).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If aligning the text inside the label is your problem then above solutions are good.
If setting the frame is the problem then, I would suggest to keep the code clean something like-

Have a `nib` say `Cell.xib` file and a corresponding `.m` and `.h` say `Cell.m` and `Cell.h` file which is the owner of the nib file.
The `Cell` class shall be a sub class of `UITableViewCell` . Place the `UILables/UIImageView/UIButton` in the `xib` at the needed positions and map them with a the corresponding properties in the `Cell` class(also give some `Cell identifier` in the `Cell.xib` ).

In `cellForRowatIndex` `datasource` method get the cells from the nib like-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    Cell *cell = (Cell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];//same CellIdentifier as in the Cell.xib
                    if(cell==nil){
                 cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell"  owner:self        options:nil] lastObject]; 
            }

        //Access and set the labels, imageViews here

            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_titleTextField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69, 29, _titleTextField.frame.size.width, _titleTextField.frame.size.height)];
```

This is strange. You are setting the width and height of the label from its own width and height. This will set it to the width and height of the previous label. I don't know what it will do the first time you encounter this code.

Your text is being aligned to the right within the bounds of the label view, but the bounds are not ending up where you want them. You can try setting the background color so you can see where the frame of your label is.

```
_titleTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

You should just set it to fill the space of the cell, and let it position the text within it. Making a label's frame too large won't affect the size of the text, although making it too small might, depending on the options set.

```
_titleTextField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69, 29, 273 - 69, self.contentview.bounds.size.height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10+ & Swift 3+

```
titleTextField.textAlignment = .center
lblTitle.textAlignment = .right
```